# Classification with SVD — Eigenfaces

Tags: matrices, machine-learning, svd, neural-networks

I just saw a play list on YouTube where Professor [Steve Brunton](https://www.youtube.com/@Eigensteve) teaches how the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD) works and its applications, e.g., [classification via the SVD](https://youtu.be/gXbThCXjZFM). What is the difference between classification via SVD, say, `[U,S,V] = svd(A)`, compared to the neural network $a = \sigma(Wx + b)$?

All I know that SVD have a "data bank", and neural networks...have not a "data bank" to compare with.

**Question:**

I know how to use classification for neural networks. But how can I do that for SVD?

Comment: The two things aren't really comparable.  SVD is a kind of principle component analysis, and so depending on what kind of neural network you're using, I suppose that you could say that both techniques use feature detection of some sort, but really the techniques are quite orthogonal to each other.  You could, for example, use SVD to do dimensional reduction, and then perform classification via a neural network on the reduced data, or use any clustering algorithm, but it is very different from the feature detection of a CNN.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for reply. So you mean that SVD can be used to "split up" the image like localization, and then use a neural network for classification?

Comment: Sort of? In the case of faces, imagine you had a large collection of images of faces, each image being viewed as a vector which becomes a column (or row, depending on conventions) of a big matrix.  If you have enough faces in your database, you might expect that every normal face is going to be some combination of other faces in different proportions.  If you want to classify faces, you want to find features that vary the most between faces, and SVD helps you figure out what these features are.  But they aren't local, as local features can be correlated.

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The question is about how far can I reach with classical image classification methods compared to neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVD itself is a form of PCA.With EigenFaces you can decompose the Image into its constituents and use these vectors as features for an Classifier.
So think of it as a feature extraction technique for images of faces .